# Make [esprima.js] a synonym of [esprima]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

These two tags [esprima](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esprima) and [esprima.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esprima.js) refer to the same [project](https://esprima.org/). As you can see the project homepage doesn't refer to itself as "esprima.js". The NPM package is "esprima" too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found at least [one instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62120029/4099593) of a post tagged with [esprima](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esprima) that wasn't related to the javascript Esprima. I created a new tag for the [Python esprima package](https://github.com/Kronuz/esprima-python). Apart from that everything else (59 of the questions) seems to be about esprima.js, so I added [esprima.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esprima.js) as a synonym for [esprima](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esprima). That is

[esprima.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esprima.js) (× 13) → [esprima](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esprima) (× 60).

Right now it doesn't look like there's a lot of confusion with respect to the Python version of esprima and esprima.js (1 question out of 73), so I'm fine with leaving this as is (with [esprima](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esprima) as the master). If in the future, this becomes an issue, we can go for a rename.